# SQL Server - how to select my transaction isolation

Tags: sql-server, transactions, isolation-level

I want to perform SQL transaction when insertion of new rows only.

what type of transaction isolation level I should follow.

Comment: Can you expand your question?

Comment: You can find everything you need here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Read this to understand your requirement. [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Either of the two should suit you:

**READ UNCOMMITTED**
Specifies that statements can read rows that have been modified by other transactions but not yet committed.

**READ COMMITTED**
Specifies that statements cannot read data that has been modified but not committed by other transactions. This prevents dirty reads. Data can be changed by other transactions between individual statements within the current transaction, resulting in nonrepeatable reads or phantom data. This option is the SQL Server default.